# Join two tables and return data and count in a single query

Tags: sql-server, join, count

I have two tables in an SQL Server database, one with two columns and one with four:

1. `tbl_email_list`

   1. `email_list_id` `int` (PK)
   2. `email_list_name` `varchar`
2. `tbl_email-details`

   1. `email_uniq_id` `int` (PK)
   2. `email_list_id` `int` (FK)
   3. `email_address` `varchar`
   4. `blacklist` `bit`

I want to retrieve data in one query which should return

1. All the email lists from tbl_email_list;
2. The total number of email_address associated with a specific email_list_id;
3. The total number of whitelisted email addresses (where blacklist=0);
4. The total number of blacklisted email addresses (where blacklist=1).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select l.email_list_id, l.email_list_name,
    count(d.email_uniq_id) as full_count,
    count(case when d.blacklist = 0 then d.email_uniq_id end) as white_count,
    count(case when d.blacklist = 1 then d.email_uniq_id end) as black_count
from tbl_email_list as l
left join [tbl_email-details] as d on d.email_list_id = l.email_list_id
group by l.email_list_id, l.email_list_name;
```

By counting things which can be null, we let zeroes appear in the result set, which is a very useful technique. Here I do it for both the blacklist results and the overall (based on the outer join).

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
el.emali_list_name AS EmailList
,COUNT(*) AS EmailsCount 
,SUM(CASE WHEN ed.blacklist = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BlackList4ListCouint
,SUM(CASE WHEN ed.blacklist = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS WhiteList4ListCouint
FROM [tbl_email_list] AS el LEFT JOIN [tbl_email-details] AS ed ON (el.email_list_id = ed.email_list_id) 
GROUP BY el.emali_list_name
ORDER BY EmailList;
```

Please check if the query gives correct results.

I presume that you don't have 2 equal emails in the same list. Otherwise in some cases the calculations will not be correct.